# Is it necessary to have Email field in ASP.NET CreateUserWizard Control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, createuserwizard

I had done the registration using  `ASP.NET CreateUserWizard Control`. In here I want to use email address as the username. I had problem removing Email field from the control. In the `web.config` file I used `requiresUniqueEmail="false"`. 
I achieve this by hiding the email field and autofilled the field with username.
There is a way [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960599/net-createuserwizard-how-to-provide-a-pre-filled-and-disabled-email-field) of doing that. 
I just wondering if there is any other better way of doing this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the [CreateUserWizard.RequireEmail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.createuserwizard.requireemail.aspx) property to false like so:

```
<asp:CreateUserWizard ID="CreateUserWizard1" runat="server" 
    RequireEmail="false" ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `RequireEmail` property to `true` or `false`. 
You can find more from [CreateUserWizard.RequireEmail Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.createuserwizard.requireemail.aspx)

```
<asp:CreateUserWizard RequireEmail="True|False" />
```